# Get GIT repo ID by commit ID with Visual Studio Online

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible in Visual Studio Online with GIT to get info about the repository the commit is in ?

With the [Visual Studio Online REST API](https://mycompany.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/494ac3b2-3396-45b3-a609-4ae2208a3c85/commits/cec471c12049248d93f25cc39cd7b8b028732fdd?api-version=1.0) I can get info about a certain commit, but I always need to know which repository it is in.

```
https://myCompany.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/
_apis/git/repositories/{REPO-ID}/commits/{COMMIT-ID}?api-version=1.0
```

Is there any way I can programatically retrieve info like REPO id by using the commit ID ?
Something like:

```
https://mycompany.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/
_apis/git/commits/{COMMIT-ID}?api-version=1.0
```

Comment: No, because the same commit id can be in multiple Repo's. That's how git works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Git a commit hash is unique (it's cryptographically calculated) to the history graph. When you push a commit from one repository to another, the hash stays the same.

You can push the same commit (with the same unique hash) to multiple remote repositories. This will result in the same hash in multiple repositories.

This is the reason you need to tell TFS the context of the commit, if you don't supply it, there are possibly multiple results.It's inherent to the distributed model of Git.